# How to get the page type which NavigationService navigates to?

Tags: template10

From a page A I nagivate to page B.
I have overrided OnNavigatedFromAsync() on page A and I'd like to know the page type I'm coming to. Is it possible to know it?

Comment: Did you try e.SourcePageType ? ( e is NavigationEventArgs )

Comment: I ended up using NavigatingCancelEventArgs of NavigationService.Frame.Navigating event. Works perfectly fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NavigatingCancelEventArgs of NavigationService.Frame.Navigating event does the trick.

It is possible to get the targetted page type via SourcePageType and cancel transition using the Cancel property.